# Why does the log show DEBUG?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream, akka-http

I've done the following configuration for akka

```
akka {
  loggers = ["akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger"]
  loglevel = "ERROR"
  logging-filter = "akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLoggingFilter"
}
```

For me it means, show only `ERROR` logs, but it shows everything:

```
17:12:20.758 [SAP-SENDER-akka.kafka.default-dispatcher-6] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer - [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=SAP-SENDER-GROUP)] Initializing the Kafka consumer
17:12:20.806 [SAP-SENDER-akka.kafka.default-dispatcher-6] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata - Updated cluster metadata version 1 to Cluster(id = null, nodes = [localhost:9092 (id: -1 rack: null)], partitions = [], controller = null)
17:12:20.811 [SAP-SENDER-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] ERROR SAP-SENDER - It is done Connection failed..
17:12:20.828 [SAP-SENDER-akka.kafka.default-dispatcher-6] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics - Added sensor with name fetch-throttle-time
17:12:20.845 [SAP-SENDER-akka.kafka.default-dispatcher-6] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics - Added sensor with name connections-closed:
17:12:20.846 [SAP-SENDER-akka.kafka.default-dispatcher-6] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics - Added sensor with name connections-created:
17:12:20.846 [SAP-SENDER-akka.kafka.default-dispatcher-6] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics - Added sensor with name successful-authentication:
```

Why does it show everything?

Comment: Maybe because you have config only for akka logs and debug logs come from another part of app

Comment: Try putting your confine inside akka{error{}}